# C++ inline class definition and object initialisation

Tags: c++, inline, definition

I've just come across the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

static class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "in foo" << std::endl;
    }

}
    blah;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "exiting" << std::endl;
    blah.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't seen the above method of definining a variable before - the class definition is done inline with the variable definition. It reminds me of anonymous classes in Java. What is this called, and is it in the C++ standard?

Thanks

Taras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite standard to define a `class` (or `struct`, perfectly equivalent except that the default is `public` instead of `private`) and declare a variable of its type (or pointer to such a variable, etc) -- it was OK in C (with `struct`, but as I already mentioned C++'s `class`, save for public vs private, is the same thing as `struct`) and C++ mostly maintains upwards compatibility with (ISO-1989) C.  Never heard it called by any special name.

Comment: Is it necessary for the class to be named in this case (i.e., are anonymous classes permitted in C++)?  And, since it is named, can you still create other `Foo` objects?

Comment: ... soon to be compatibility with ISO C99. I should add, though, that this usage is quite rare in idiomatic C++, even though it is legal.

Comment: @STingRaySC: no, anonymous classes are fine, and yes, you can create others. In fact you can create two even if it is anonymous: `struct { … } foo1, foo2;`.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that if the class is unnamed, you may not put that declaration at namespace scope. It has to be local then (the rationale is: You cannot redeclare in another TU anyway - the variables there will have a different type).